# Communication between two servers for a ddos challenge page?

Tags: php, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04

I need to develop a challenge page much similar to the Cloudflare firewall challenge.

I know how to make the front end and the back end of the challenge app and I know how to set it up on the server.

The problem comes on how to implement it to the website which is on one server, while the challenge app is on another server. How should I make the communication between the servers? Both servers will be Ubuntu 16.4. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What communication are you talking about?

Comment: @Shadow I want to "listen" to the users that visit the website and if they make several connections to it, to redirect them to the challenge page, If they solve the captcha there they should be redirect back to the website and will never be bothered again, If not, they should always be redirected to the challenge server, so they don't take the resources of the website server. I am talking about 20 million connections a day. Out of them only a few percent are real visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to solve this issue like cloudflare using nginx server.

- Make an nginx reverse proxy with rate limit
- if limit hit user will be redirected to error page
- integrate your challenge app with the error page.

more about this configuration is here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/645154/how-to-redirect-to-an-other-link-when-excess-request-limit-req-with-nginx

And How to use PHP in error pages is here:
[Nginx, PHP + FPM Custom Error Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486868/nginx-php-fpm-custom-error-pages)
you can run this reverse proxy on third server or you can run it on the challenge app server.

make your domain points to the reverse proxy
then
make nginx config

```
 server {

        listen   80 default_server;
        server_name *.*;
        client_body_timeout 5s;
        client_header_timeout 5s;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://00.00.00.00/; #replace with upstream ip
        }

}
```

you have to combine this with custom php error page

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how to make users get trough the reverse proxy server and than reach the website server when they hit the domain name?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!! One last question. I was thinking about storing every unique IP and check if the user solved the captcha once, if yes he would never be shown the challenge again. Also I want to show the error page if IP hits the limit or hits different URL than home. With this approach (the reverse proxy) I would be able to do that, right?

Comment: Yes you can. you can choose suitable technique like cookie or header based bypass

Comment: Okay, I will try it all out and will update when its done. Thank you for the assistance!